# Trying to get property 'bathrooms' of non-object Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

good I have the following error I do not understand why, if I have all my relationships well, well as far as I see .. I would like to know if they find any errors so that they do not show me my property spaces

Propertie Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Propertie extends Model
{
    //
    public function characteristic()
    {

        return $this->HasMany('App\Characteristic', 'property_id');
        
    }
    public function departament()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Departament');
        
    }
    
    public function municipality()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Detail');
        
    }
    
    public function detail()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Detail');
        
    }
    
    public function offer_type()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Offer_type','offer_type_id');
        
    }
    
    public function property_type()
    {

        return $this->hasOne('App\Property_type','id','property_type_id');
        
    }
    public function space()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Space', 'spaces_id');
        
    }
    
     public function ImgProperties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ImgProperties');
    }
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'property_type_id', 'offer_type', 'spaces_id', 'departaments_id',
        'municipalities_id', 'details_id', 'characteristics_id', 'images','url', 'lat', 'lng','direction','price'

    ];
```

Migration Propertie

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable;
            $table->string('price')->nullable;
            $table->text('description')->nullable;
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('property_type_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('offer_type_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('spaces_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('departaments_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('municipalities_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('details_id')->nullable();
            //$table->unsignedBigInteger('characteristics_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('images')->nullable;
            $table->float('lat')->nullable;
            $table->float('lng')->nullable;
            $table->string('address')->nullable;
            
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->foreign('property_type_id')->references('id')->on('property_type');
            $table->foreign('offer_type_id')->references('id')->on('offer_type');
            $table->foreign('spaces_id')->references('id')->on('spaces');
            $table->foreign('departaments_id')->references('id')->on('departaments');
            $table->foreign('municipalities_id')->references('id')->on('municipalities');
            $table->foreign('details_id')->references('id')->on('details');
           //$table->foreign('characteristics_id')->references('id')->on('characteristics')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

Spaces migration

```
   */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('spaces', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('property_id')->references('id')->on('properties')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('bedrooms');
            $table->string('bathrooms');
            $table->string('parking');
            $table->string('area');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

index method

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
       
       $name = $request->get('name');
   
        if($request->p_type){
            
            $properties = Propertie::typeof($request->p_type);
        }elseif($request->sorttype){
            
            $properties = Propertie::sorttype($request->sorttype);
         
        }else{
            
            
            $properties = Propertie::with('space')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
         ->name($name)
         ->paginate(5);
         
        }
        
      
         $property_type = Property_type::all();
         $spaces = Space::all();
    
        return view('properties.index',compact('properties','property_type'));
        
    }
```

recently it worked for me but from one moment to the next it does not recognize my relationship, I have done dd in the index and the relationship is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change the relationship to this.

```
public function space()
{

    return $this->hasOne('App\Space', 'property_id');
    
}
```